# Use greasemonkey to add images into any web page?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I want to be able to add a pre-defined set of images onto various websites in FireFox - this is to enable a personal extension to work.

I think I should be able to do this in GreaseMonkey - can anyone confirm if I am looking in the right direction before I go further down this road?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a variety of ways.
Here's a complete working script to get you started:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Add an image to a web page
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("body").append (
    '<img id="myNewImage" src="http://i37.photobucket.com/albums/e77/kpeaton/unicorn.jpg">'
);
$("#myNewImage").css ( {
    position:   "fixed",
    width:      "128px",
    height:     "128px",
    top:        "0",
    left:       "0"
} );
```